# Converter acentos, &ordm e espaços em hífens

Tags: php

Tenho um sistema de upload do qual ao subir um arquivo com esse tipo de nomenclatura:

> Lei 4.472 - 2015 - Altera a Lei nº 4.000 de 10 de julho de 2013 -
>   Arquivo Particular.pdf

Estou retirando os espaços e acentos da seguinte forma:

```
$arquivo = $_FILES["Arquivo"]['name'];
$extensao = pathinfo($arquivo);
$extensao = $extensao['extension'];
list($nomeArquivo,$extensaoArquivo) = explode(".".$extensao,$arquivo);
$novoNome = strtolower( preg_replace("[^a-zA-Z0-9-.]", "-", strtr(utf8_decode(trim($nomeArquivo)), utf8_decode("áàãâéêíóôõúüñçÁÀÃÂÉÊÍÓÔÕÚÜÑÇ."), "aaaaeeiooouuncAAAAEEIOOOUUNC-")) );
$arquivo $novoNome.".".$extensao;
```

Porém quando o arquivo tem `º`, aparece o sinal de `?`. Como posso corrigir isso fazendo com que esse sinal também seja modificado para hífen?

Comment: Mudei para: `$novoNome = strtolower( preg_replace("[^a-zA-Z0-9-]", "-", strtr(utf8_decode(trim($nomeArquivo)), utf8_decode("áàãâéêíóôõúüñçÁÀÃÂÉÊÍÓÔÕÚÜÑÇº."), "aaaaeeiooouuncAAAAEEIOOOUUNC-")) );` porém o *ponto* não converte para hífen

Comment: Boa tarde @Fox.11 .. Cara não é só colocar o  º na string "[^a-zA-Z0-9-.º]" ? Eu ate tentei reproduzir esse o com traço embaixo aqui.. mas só consegui no word. :)

Comment: Olá Ricardo. Tentei dessa forma, mas não funcionou.

Comment: Boa tarde @Fox.11 . Como você conseguiu colocar o O com traço embaixo aqui?? quais as combenições de tecla que você usuou??

Comment: Boa tarde Ricardo. Aqui não consigo visualizar essa letra. Ela está onde exatamente?

Answer (score 0):

Fiz dessa forma e parece que funcionou, mas se estiver errado, podem me corrigir:

```
$novoNome = strtolower( preg_replace("[^a-zA-Z0-9-|\.]", "-", strtr(utf8_decode(trim($nomeArquivo)), utf8_decode("áàãâéêíóôõúüñçÁÀÃÂÉÊÍÓÔÕÚÜÑÇº."), "aaaaeeiooouuncAAAAEEIOOOUUNC-")) );
```